# Javascript/React: Change displayed SVG background based on state value

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, background-image

I am working on a project for my Bootcamp. Design isn't the focus, but I want to go for the whole kaboodle: have both a working product and a good-looking front end to display it. I am using a .SVG as the displayed background set via CSS, and thus far I've succeeded in changing the displayed SVG based on CSS media queries. However, I'm interested in the possibility of having it change based on a value held in state/props.

The point of the project is an image viewer and user vote/ranking system. I was thinking to have backgrounds change based on the photo's category, which will be a value held in the state inside of the array holding the photo/user data. Let's say the category is "Dog" and I want to display a corresponding background. But when the user changes to another photo and its category is "Cat", I would like to have a different background displayed. I am working with animated SVGs for the backgrounds.

What's the best way for me to do this? I figure I can add the code into my functions that are being used to change the displayed photos.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles based on state value directly.

Also you can youse ReactSvg package. It allows you to access nodes inside svg.

```
<ReactSVG beforeInjection={(svg) => { 
    const myStyleClass = this.state.myStyle == 'x' ? 'y' : 'z';
    svg.classList.add(''); 
}} src={myImportedImage} />
```

Comment: since I am using the SVG as a background I am calling it in via CSS className assigned to the top level Div of my component return, like so -> 
```
#svgbkg {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 90%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url(../../Styles/SVG/Backgrounds/paw1.svg)
```
with media queries to change SVG based on size. How best can I change this via state, or should I refactor this into calling it in as an imported component?

Comment: So, you can create high order component for top level div and read state inside, set styling based on value. Check out https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components